# Combine checkbox required jQuery code to shorten code

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have some jQuery code that I implemented but it seem too redundant to use so I wanted to see if anyone would be able to assist me in figuring out if there is a way to reduce the amount of code that I'm using.

What I'm doing: When a user clicked the checkbox, the fields become required but if it's not checked, then they're not required.

**Here are the images of the working functionality**:
[image] 
[image]

**Code**:

```
/* Make checkbox textboxes not required unless checked */
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rtk5').change(function() {
        if ($('#rtk5Field1').attr('required')) {
            $('#rtk5Field1').removeAttr('required');
        }
        else {
            $('#rtk5Field1').attr('required','required');
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rtk5').change(function() {
        if ($('#rtk5Field2').attr('required')) {
            $('#rtk5Field2').removeAttr('required');
        }
        else {
            $('#rtk5Field2').attr('required','required');
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rtk5').change(function() {
        if ($('#rtk5Field3').attr('required')) {
            $('#rtk5Field3').removeAttr('required');
        }
        else {
            $('#rtk5Field3').attr('required','required');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: For working code looking for improvement, try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use only one `$(document).ready` function. And second, use only one `change` function. If you give all your fields the same class (for instance, `reqFields`), you can target them all in one shot.  So your new code could look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rtk5').change(function() {
        if ($('.reqFields').attr('required')) {
            $('.reqFields').removeAttr('required');
        }
        else {
            $('.reqFields').attr('required','required');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the input @thingEvery, what if I'm already using the class name such as class="form-control" for all of my other text inputs outside of this checkbox such as targeting css and such - Would it be possible to base them off ids instead?

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents An element can have as many classes as you like, so just add a new class just for the fields you want  to affect.

Comment: ahh totally forgot! Thanks so much!